# Does all 802.11ax routers include MU-MIMO?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, 802.11n

I'm trying to buy a new router and had a question that I couldn't find anywhere else. Do all 802.11ax routers come with MU-MIMO? How can I tell if a router supports MU-MIMO?

Comment: The specifications for the router will indicate if it supports MU-MIMO

Comment: To add to @Ramhound's comment, not every 802.11ax router will have Mu-MIMO, though most will have it most likely. Look in the spec sheets of a particular router to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ramhound mentioned, it will be specified in the router's specifications if it can support MU-MIMO. Not all 802.11ax routers will support MU-MIMO.